# How to send an email using groovy script in Soap UI?

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api, groovyscriptengine

I want to send an automated email once all my test steps are passed in SOAP UI, using a groovy script test step??
Is there a way that we can achieve this ??

Comment: Please post your sample code. If there is anything you had tried

Comment: A couple of options to consider if you don't want o write your own email test step: 1) If you can afford it, soapUI Pro has a built-in email test step. 2) Run your soapUI project from Jenkins and rely on Jenkins notifications.

Comment: you can try following link: https://testarenablog.wordpress.com/2016/08/16/send-email-in-soap-ui-using-groovy/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a Java library such as [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org) and call it from Groovy in a Groovy Script Test Step. You can add external jars in the bin/ext directory of your SoapUI install, and they will be added to the classpath next time the tool is started. If you use the samples from a library, you can use the Java, in most cases Java is valid Groovy. If the library examples have several classes, you should be able to have it all in one Groovy script.